# Why would file input throw EAGAIN on read?

Tags: c++, unix

I have a program reading in from a file, doin some work on the input, then outputing it to a socket.  It's been running fine for over a month when suddenly I started to get error 11 (EAGAIN?) error that kill the program.  When I start 32 instances of the program more then half die within a few minutes receiving EAGAIN messages.  I never set the file as non-blocking and besides which how would an input file block, the data is always there isn't it?  The only change i made to this code was to disable the sigpipe signal to avoid the program dieing when it's socket connection is lost.

Forgive me for not posting code, but I can't copy and paste and the code is sort of spread out anyways.  It's really as simple as opening a file on one line and calling readline(file, inputString) later on though.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you handling `EAGAIN`? It just tells you the blocking call was interrupted somehow and you should try the operation again that received the error.

Comment: as of now i'm not handling it, thus the program exploding. I'm more trying to figure out why a file read would need to block, the data is always there on the file isn't it?  and why wouldn't it just block if it had to, does it open as non-blocking by default

Comment: As I mentioned `EAGAIN` is just issued if the (i guess) `read()` call was interrupted by a signal and can't be finished properly. That has nothing to do with the file itself but may have to do with your changes with signal handling.

Comment: `EAGAIN` typically means your I/O is on a non-blocking descriptor, and this result is notification that the operation would block. Are you sure you are getting `EAGAIN` and not `EINTR`? `EINTR` is what usually indicates the I/O has been interrupted.

Comment: "*Forgive me for not posting code*" - You are forgiven, but that doesn't mean you're going to get any useful help. If you can produce a short, complete program that demonstrates the problem, then you'll get better help, quicker. If you can't reproduce the problem in a short program, then that might give you a clue about what is going wrong. See http://sscce.org for more details.

Comment: "*I started to get error 11*" - What, precisely does that mean? That `readline` returned an 11? That some part of your program printed an 11? That the program exited with a return code of 11?

Comment: the readline call returned a -1 but errno is 11.  which should be EAGAIN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EAGAIN means that the read has been interrupted by a signal and that it should be restarted.

I assume it is the SIGPIPE which used to directly kill your programs and now is handled (even if the handling is to do nothing).